# Find normal of a point and determine if another point is to the same side of the normal

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to optimise an algorithm but I'm stuck on a subproblem... it doesn't seem hard but I don't remember as much linear algebra/geometry as I probably should. Any help is welcome.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^r$ with $b=\mathbf{0}$ and $a \neq b$. I can calculate the distance $d$ between $a$ and $b$ if needed. I'd like to be able to find a line $l$ that is perpendicular to the line $ba$. My real need is that given a point $c \in \mathbb{R}^r$ I should be able to tell whether or not $c$ is to the same side of $l$ as $a$.

A quick analogy: if $b$ is a person facing $a$, is the object $c$ to the front or back of $b$?

Any ideas of how I can calculate that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ a = (a_1,...,a_r)$ and $b = 0. $ The plane which has $a$ as a normal vector is the plane of equation
$$ a_1x +a_2x+...+a_rx_r = 0.$$
Any line inside this plane is perpendicular to the line passing through $a$ and $b$.

In particular this plane separates the space $\mathbb R^r$ in two and for any $c = (c_1,...,c_r) \in \mathbb R^r$, the point $c$ lies on the same side of the plane as $a$ if and only if $ a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + ... + a_rc_r $ is positive. If it is negative then $a$ and $c$ lie on opposite sides of the plane.

More generally if $b \neq 0$ then you should look at the sign of the dot product of the vectors $\vec{ba}$ and $\vec{bc}$

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is on the same side as $b$ as $a$ is, then either $d(a, c) < d(b, c)$ (it is on the same side of the perpendicular bisector of $ab$ as $a$ is, or, the triangle $abc$ will be an obtuse triangle with $d(a, c) \geq d(b, c)$. In this second case, we should have $d(a,c) \leq \sqrt{d(b,c)^2+d(a,b)^2}$. Quite fortunately, the first condition is actually implied by the second so you only have to check that $d(a,c) \leq \sqrt{d(b,c)^2+d(a,b)^2}$ to know whether the point $c$ is on the same side of $b$ as $a$ is.

(note, in case you want to consider separately if $c$ is on the line through $b$ perpendicular to $ab$, check separately if $d(a,c) = \sqrt{d(b,c)^2+d(a,b)^2} $

[image: an image showing the points a, b, and c and the triangle they form.]